# Get percentage rate between two metrics in a define interval [Prometheus]

Tags: service, prometheus, metrics, promql

I have a question about Prometheus. In my service I have 2 Counters, metric_1 is the total number of requests and metric_2 is the number of failed requests. I need to derive a further metric from these to determine the error rate of requests in terms of percentage in a defined interval (e.g. 2 hours). How can I achieve this through, for example, PromQL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like the following:

```
increase(metric_2[2h]) / increase(metric_1[2h])
```

See [increase() function documention](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#increase).

It is assumed that `metric_1` and `metric_2` are [counters](https://prometheus.io/docs/concepts/metric_types/#counter). If these metrics are [gauges](https://prometheus.io/docs/concepts/metric_types/#gauge), then `increase()` must be substituted by [sum_over_time()](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#aggregation_over_time).

Comment: Thanks a lot! And do you know what type is the derived metric? I assume it is a Gauge.

Comment: If the metric value may go up and down with each scrape, then this is a gauge. If it starts from 0 and then constantly grows, then this is a counter.

Comment: So its type is managed at runtime, based on the values that it can assume?